# Why is pandas read_csv able to find file but os.listdir isn't?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I have a file at `~/Google Drive/iNat/full.csv`.

```
iNatPATH = r"~/Google Drive/iNat/"
FILENAME = iNatPATH + "full.csv"
```

I can't figure out why Pandas is able to read the `csv` file:

```py
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)

# no error returned.
```

But `os` can't find it:

```py
import os
os.path.exists(FILENAME)

# outputs False
```

I am running this code in a macOS system on a local runtime in Google Colab.

My working directory is (not supposed to be relevant since I am using the absolute path):

```py
>>> os.getcwd()
...
'/Users/<myusername>/Documents'
```

Comment: I would bet that `os.path.exists` doesn't expand the `~` character. Seems like you should apply `os.path.expanduser(path)` before to the path variable. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

Comment: Nice :) Let me write an appropriate answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `os.path.exists()` function doesn't expand the `~` character. To solve this, the same `os` module provides the `os.path.expanduser(path)` function that will expand that user variable in a path for you.

Applied to your case:

```py
iNatPATH = r"~/Google Drive/iNat/"
FILENAME = iNatPATH + "full.csv"

# Expand the ~ character
FILENAME = os.path.expanduser(FILENAME)

# Finally you can check again with exists() function
os.path.exists(FILENAME)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, where `os.list.dir()` returned a path and then subsequently `pd.read_csv()` threw a `FileNotFound` error and also`os.path.exists()` returned `False`.

If anyone encounters the same error, check that your filename does not exceed 259 characters (Windows) or 255 characters (MacOS).

*(While not a direct answer to the question, it's very likely that individuals experiencing this problem may land on this stackoverflow page, as I did.)*